# Is there any way to trigger a specific Github action workflow by commit message value?

Tags: triggers, workflow, github-actions, commit

Is there any way to trigger a specific Github action workflow by commit-message value? For example, if I push with the commit message "smoke_test", only (one specific workflow ) smoke test workflow should trigger from a set of workflows. Please help, thanks!

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#startswith

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#using-contexts-to-access-environment-variable-values

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is. You can inspect trigger event if commit message contains specific keyword.

Here's an example:

```
name: Smoke tests
on: push

jobs:
 test:
   runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
   steps:
     - name: Run smoke tests
       if: contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'smoke_test')
       run: |
         echo 'Running smoke tests!'
```

Comment: It is good enough, but this actually creates a workflow run, and then just skips the step

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There is a way. I have not found official documentation available within this link with a CFG description of the used script language.

Experiments that I have carried out show that you can use `if` keyword to condition all steps in **Job**. See, the example below.

And it's nicer compared to [Using conditions to control job execution](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution) because if all steps are not executed the build is marked as grey in GitHub CI.

### Example

```
name: My Build.

# The name for workflow runs generated from the workflow, which will appear in the list of workflow.

run-name: ${{ github.actor }} has triggered Build and Launch Unittests for the project 

# Specify the trigger for this workflow.
on: [push]


jobs:
  Build-my-project-for-Linux:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'please build')
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: echo " The ${{ github.repository }} repository has been cloned to the runner into " ${{ github.workspace }}
      - run: |
         export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-10
         export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-10
         echo "Etc. for first step"
      - run: |
         echo "Etc. for second step"
```

---

### Appendix

#### Links to the official documentation

[1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-conditions-to-control-job-execution) https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions

[2] https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows

#### Terminology used in CI in GitHub workflows

**Workflow** - is a configurable automated process that will run one or more jobs

**Event** - is a specific activity in a repository that triggers a workflow run.

**Runner** - is a server that runs your workflows when they're triggered. Each runner can run a single job at a time. GitHub provides Ubuntu Linux, Microsoft Windows, and macOS runners.

**Job** - is a set of steps in a workflow that executes on the same runner.

**Step** - step is either a shell script that will be executed or an action that will be run.

**Action** - is a custom application for the GitHub Actions platform that performs a complex but frequently repeated task.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to [skipping step/job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70378405/3736955) by checking commit message (after workflow started to run) is using `paths:` to check if specific file is changed in that commit, instead of commit message content. This way your workflow never starts to run, unlike the other approach:

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '**trigger_file.txt'
```

You can combine both approaches, to make trigger explicit